# Are these button native from the google maps component in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

The app is [Cups](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citylifeapps.cups) and when you click a marker appears two button

One for route and one for navigation

[image]

I search into google maps api v2 for Android and I didnt find do that native.

Is a function to do that and if there isnt, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

no those are not built into the maps API all they did was create an image that looks like the my location button. to do something like that you would have to create a view that lays ontop of the map an position them where you want

Comment: a relative layout, the map and the buttons in another layer. It's ok. And when I clicked in a marker, I set visibily to true